# How to make screenshots high resolution

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, screenshot

I have multiple screenshots and it appears that when I put them into illustrator and click off the image it then becomes pixalated. Is there a possible way to make this clear. As I don't have the original files I **NEED** to use the screenshots.

Comment: It's a screen shot. Of course it's pixelated. That's OK.

Comment: this was posted by the same user. It's certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Open screenshot in photoshop
Go to: image/image size
Set resolution to 300dpi
make sure scale styles, constrain proportions, and resample image are all checked.
Replace into illustrator.  Although it will be smaller, it will be at the correct 300dpi resolution.

Comment: However, you cannot make it "high resolution" at the same size you are bringing it into illustrator as.  Right now, it is bringing it in at 72dpi.  Once you make it 300dpi, it should place at the maximum, highest resolution it can possibly be.  You cannot go from small to big with resolution terms.  Only big to small.